# Using @JavascriptInterface send value to assets/map.html

Tags: javascript, java, android, google-maps

I get Latitude,Longitude and send it to map.html
However I try two ways.

First.I give two value type is "double"
and this way is success

```
@JavascriptInterface
    public double getLatitude() {
        return 25.03314;
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public double getLongitude() {
        return 121.5637343;
    }
```

but next,I use onLocationChanged(Location location) in activity
get my Latitude,Longitude

and send , but this way is fail.
I don't know where have error
because haven't error message

so if I want react the function what I to do ?

```
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getLatitude(location.getLatitude());
    getLongitude(location.getLongitude());

}
@JavascriptInterface
public double getLatitude(double lat) {
    Log.e("TAG",String.valueOf(lat));
    return lat;
}
@JavascriptInterface
public double getLongitude(double lon) {
    Log.e("TAG",String.valueOf(lon));
    return lon;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double lat = 0.0,lat=0.0;
```

change to

```
static double lat = 0.0,lat=0.0;
```

and

```
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    lat = location.getLatitude();
    lon = location.getLongitude();

}
@JavascriptInterface
public double getLatitude() {
    Log.e("TAG",String.valueOf(lat));
    return lat;
}
@JavascriptInterface
public double getLongitude() {
    Log.e("TAG",String.valueOf(lon));
    return lon;
}
```